# Sort by date with comparison, returns wrong order in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, ecmascript-6, compare

I get the data from firebase

```
componentWillMount() {
  let athleteRef = fire.database()
    .ref("athlete")
    .orderByChild("email")
    .equalTo(this.state.email)

  athleteRef
    .once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((data) => {

        let workload: number = data.val().minutes * data.val().intensity;
        let datas = data.val();

        let workouts = {
          key: data.key,
          date: datas.dateCreated,
          athleteData: data.val(),
          workload: workload,
        };
        this.setState({ workouts: [workouts].concat(this.state.workouts) });
    })
  });
}
```

I made this sort function

```
sortByDate(arr) {
  if(this.state.sortedByDate === true) {
    let sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => {
      new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime());
    }
    this.setState({
      workouts: sorted,
      sortedByDate: false,
    });
  } else {
    let sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => {
      new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime());
    }
    this.setState({
      workouts: sorted,
      sortedByDate: true,
    });
  }
}
```

The array looks like this after being sorted desc (notice year 2016):

```
Array (11)
{key: "-KyocQLyhpwVHCpKJOBv", date: "13/11/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 1}
{key: "-KyR0ovLXga6zlHX4J40", date: "08/11/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 30}
{key: "-KyPny-m5OjAdK0C133e", date: "08/11/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 80}
{key: "-KvRKjbTmbvajvcijYl2", date: "02/10/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 72}
{key: "-KvOv-2gZ1U46btx62Lg", date: "01/09/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 120}
{key: "-KyR0rqVt34A-_TYdpH9", date: "01/01/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 60006}
{key: "-KyR0qf78bi7S1xE7QyE", date: "01/01/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 100000}
{key: "-KvXHVN6MsfQS-j6aAx9", date: "01/01/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 100000}
{key: "-KyR0kW7WWE9N5SIM9hz", date: "01/01/2016", athleteData: Object, workload: 5000000000}
{key: "-KvMBqOTfcQpf1nJsY-V", date: "21/09/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 80}
{key: "-KvMBbaNmbeg9h66YNoj", date: "01/10/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 100}
```

After i run the asc part of the function I get:

```
{key: "-KyocQLyhpwVHCpKJOBv", date: "13/11/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 1}
{key: "-KyR0kW7WWE9N5SIM9hz", date: "01/01/2016", athleteData: Object, workload: 5000000000}
{key: "-KyR0rqVt34A-_TYdpH9", date: "01/01/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 60006}
{key: "-KyR0qf78bi7S1xE7QyE", date: "01/01/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 100000}
{key: "-KvXHVN6MsfQS-j6aAx9", date: "01/01/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 100000}
{key: "-KvOv-2gZ1U46btx62Lg", date: "01/09/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 120}
{key: "-KvRKjbTmbvajvcijYl2", date: "02/10/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 72}
{key: "-KyR0ovLXga6zlHX4J40", date: "08/11/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 30}
{key: "-KyPny-m5OjAdK0C133e", date: "08/11/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 80}
{key: "-KvMBqOTfcQpf1nJsY-V", date: "21/09/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 80}
{key: "-KvMBbaNmbeg9h66YNoj", date: "01/10/2017", athleteData: Object, workload: 100}
```

So... yeah it's almost right, but a few records all out of place :)

I also tried making the dates with

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

but that gives the same output... Any suggestions as to why?
Thanks!

Comment: Remove the extra `{}` braces from the sort functions.

Comment: Where do you put the log command? Right after `arr.sort(...)` ?

Comment: It is not a good idea to make `async` calls in `componentWillMount()` as this method will not wait for the data to be returned before calling the `render()`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning... So where should i load the data then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing string into Date constructor is discouraged [see date MDN page for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). The correct way to sort it would be to use Moment and pass it format and convert it into timestamp used for sorting.

For readability, I moved it to a separate function and generalized data (make sure you access `date` poperty in your case):

```
const data = [//this is your data]
const dateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY'
const sorted = data.sort(
 (a, b) =>
 moment(a, dateFormat).unix() - moment(b, dateFormat).unix()
)
```

Another thing is that setting `setState` in React is async because it may be batched or deferred until later. The correct way to set state based on the previous one would be to use callback passed to `setState`. Simplified code for your example would be:

```
this.setState(state => {
  return {
    sortedByDate: !state.sortedByDate,
    sorted: // do sorting here :)
  }
})
```

Comment: BTW, load your data after a component is mounted: `componentDidMount`.